# representation of compact supported distribution 

Tags: tag-removed, fa.functional-analysis

Is this true?

Any compact supported distribution can be represented as finite sum of partial derivatives of functions.

Comment: This is Theorem 6.27 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*

Answer (score 1):

This is  a theorem in Laurent Schwartz' classic monograph *Theorie des Distributions*,  Thm. XXVI, Chap. III, Sec. 7.

Answer (score 0):

http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/mth627/docs/627w2004_compact_support.pdf